# How to detect when a user changes their name?

Tags: hooks, profiles

I am trying to detect when a user changes their name.

I have tried using the `profile_update` hook:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );
function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update

I can access the `$_POST` data to get the new name fields, but `$old_user_data` does not contain the name fields, and because this fires after the data get saved, the old names fields are not in the database either.

I looked through `user.php`, and the best I see is filters for each name field, for example:

```
$meta['first_name'] = apply_filters( 'pre_user_first_name', $first_name );
```

I would prefer something that gives me access to all the data, though, instead of checking each name individually.

Is there a hook that fires after the form is submitted but before the data is saved?

I'm wanting to do something like this:

`if ($new_first_name != $old_first_name) { //store old_first_name }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook you're looking for is `insert_user_meta`.

```
add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', function( $meta, $user, $update ) {
  if( true !== $update ) return $meta;
  $old_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
  if( $old_meta[ 'first_name' ] !== $meta[ 'first_name' ] ) {
    //* Do something
  }
  return $meta;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  That's very helpful!  It's not exactly what I was wanting, as I was hoping to be able to process the whole form at once.  But it does do what I was looking for 1 field at a time.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to fire whether on update OR create...is there a way to make sure this only fires on update and not create? `if( true !== $update ) return;` does not seem to work...

Comment: It should have been returning `$meta`. It does now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out and actually just modified it to be `if($update) {//do stuff} return $meta;`